# How does one use tc to add latency to a ratelimit?

Tags: tc, netfilter

I read that there's another tool for netfilter that allows you to add latency to a ratelimit.

Does anyone have an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following script to emulate various network conditions:

```
#!/bin/bash

intf="dev eth0"
delay="delay 400ms 100ms 50%"
loss="loss random 0%"
corrupt="corrupt 0%"
duplicate="duplicate 0%"
reorder="reorder 0%"
rate="rate 512kbit"

tc qdisc del $intf root
tc qdisc add $intf root netem $delay $loss $corrupt $duplicate $reorder $rate

echo "Cancel with:"
echo "tc qdisc del $intf root"
```

In your case, to introduce a 400ms delay and a rate limit of 512kbit/s on outgoing packets on device eth0:

```
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 400ms rate 512kbit
```

References:

- [man tc-netem](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-netem.8.html)
- [Linux Foundation Netem Wiki](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem)